# Replace matrix values for each array element

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing

I have a 3-dimensional array `arr` where each array element is a matrix with the same number of rows and columns. Then I have a 3-column matrix `m` where the first two columns specify an index (row and column) and the last column a value.

```
arr = array(0, dim = c(2, 2, 3))
m = matrix(c(1, 2, -100, 2, 1, -99), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(m) = c("row_index", "column_index", "value")
```

Now I want to fill in this value at the specified indexes for each of the array elements. I couldn't find a better way to do this than the following lines of code, but I would prefer a solution with less code repetition. What's the best way to do this?

```
arr[, , 1][m[, 1:2]] = m[, 3]
arr[, , 2][m[, 1:2]] = m[, 3]
arr[, , 3][m[, 1:2]] = m[, 3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this apply approach:

```
arr[] <- apply(arr, 3, FUN = function(x) {x[m[,1:2]] <- m[,3]; x})

arr
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0 -100
# [2,]  -99    0
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0 -100
# [2,]  -99    0
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0 -100
# [2,]  -99    0
```

Comment: Nice. Could also use `replace` in the above code: `replace(arr, TRUE, apply(arr, 3, replace, m[, 1:2], m[, 3]))
`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks. That outer `replace` is quite interesting

Comment: Excellent! I tried `arr <- apply(arr, 3, FUN = function(x) {x[m[,1:2]] <- m[,3]; x})`, which gives a different result. What is the difference to `arr[] <- ...`?

Comment: @needRhelp the empty `[]` is used to keep the original structure of `arr`

Comment: would be nice if `idx <- array(m[, 1:2], c(2, 2, 3)); arr[idx] <- m[, 3]` worked